# MAMP Virtual Host site not showing images. (Laravel 4 Project)

Tags: image, laravel, laravel-4, mamp

I am running a localhost website on my virtual host through MAMP.  None of the images are showing up for this website.  Even a Facebook image pulled by using:

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/fbid/picture">
```

is not showing up.  None of the images appear broken, it just appears blank.  When I look at the source and click on the image links, they appear just fine.

All of the CSS appears, but the images aren't appearing (again, they're not appearing as broken links, but are just not appearing).  Event images pulled from the Facebook graph are not showing.

These same images are showing fine on my Mediatemple hosted website.

I am on a Mac OS X 10.7.5 machine.  The Laravel project root directory is in Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crowdsets/laravel-master.

I set up my virtual host like so:

```
<VirtualHost *>

DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crowdsets/laravel-master/public"

ServerName crowdtest.dev

</VirtualHost>
```

This issue didn't arise until a week or so ago.  Before then, all of the images appeared fine.  I did not change anything.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a stupid mistake where I had a piece of CSS that had the img tag with a z-index of -1.  Thus, none of the images showed up.